# PostgresSQL - User with access ONLY to views

Tags: postgresql

I need to configure a user with an access to any views current and future without specify everytime the GRANT to the new ones.

Is it possibile?

I've searched on google but any solution user a single GRANT query like this:

```
CREATE VIEW chartio_read_only.”Visitors” AS SELECT * FROM Visitors; GRANT SELECT ON chartio_read_only.”Visitors” TO chartio_schema_user;
```

I need something more global.

Comment: Look at the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800759/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-having-public-and-private-functions-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

Use [default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) to give the user access to all future tables and views and use `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA` to grant access to the existing ones.

Then put the tables into one schema and the view into another one. If you `GRANT` the `USAGE` privilege on the schema with the views, but not the schema with the tables, you have achieved your goal.

Comment: Question: A user with read permission on a specific schema with views, can access view's data that is created joining table from other schemas he has no access?